# How to make Clone of iframe using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Everyone i have two div id like 
I have an  in  and i am getting its content onscroll using jquery.

```
now i want onscroll pause the video in "myplayer" and it should play from same time in "getMyPlayer"
```

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   /* alert(scroll);*/
   if(scroll > 600)
   {
     $('#getMyPlayer').css('display','block');
   }
   else
   {
     $( '#myplayer' ).clone().appendTo( '#getMyPlayer' );
     $('#getMyPlayer').css('display','none'); 
   }
});
```

```html
<div id="myplayer">
<iframe width="500" height="500" src="//www.ytapi.com/embed/<?php echo $yt->id ?>?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div> 
<div id="getMyPlayer"></div>
```

Comment: Please reformat the question, it's not clear. If you want to clone it, why not simply add in two <iframe> ?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add iframe to the selector before .clone().

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   /* alert(scroll);*/
   if(scroll > 600)
   {
     $('#getMyPlayer').css('display','block');
   }
   else
   {
     $( '#myplayer iframe' ).clone().appendTo( '#getMyPlayer' ); // this line is different
     $('#getMyPlayer').css('display','none'); 
   }
});
```

Be careful though because every time the scroll position is updated it will run this code. I would recommend adding an if statement to check if it's already been copied before cloning it.

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   /* alert(scroll);*/
   if(scroll > 600)
   {
     $('#getMyPlayer').css('display','block');
   }
   else
   {
     if ($( '#getMyPlayer iframe' ).length === 0) {
         $( '#myplayer iframe' ).clone().appendTo( '#getMyPlayer' ); 
         $('#getMyPlayer').css('display','none'); 
     }
   }
});
```